# Staging Modified Files

Tags: git, github

I am reading the Pro Git book 
from 
[https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository][1]
and trying to understand staging. In the book it mentions

> Let’s change a file that was already tracked. If you change a previously tracked file called CONTRIBUTING.md and then run your git status command again, you get something that looks like this:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   README

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   CONTRIBUTING.md
```

My questions is what command is used to modify CONTRIBUTING.md and where did it come from.

Comment: Not specified.... but have fun with any text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about that book, but if you wanted to reproduce the `git status` that you have pasted, this is the easiest way to do it.

```
$ git init
$ touch CONTRIBUTING.md
$ git add CONTRIBUTING.md 
$ git commit -m "Committing initial CONTRIBUTING.md file."
[master (root-commit) e9cb706] Committing initial CONTRIBUTING.md file.
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 CONTRIBUTING.md
$ touch README
$ echo "Different contents." > CONTRIBUTING.md 
$ git add README
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   README

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   CONTRIBUTING.md

$
```

> What command is used to modify `CONTRIBUTING.md`?

Any modification to the file will do. I used `echo`, but you could also use `cat` or `vi` or open the file in VSCode to edit.

> Where did `CONTRIBUTING.md` come from?

It's an example file that they have created in their repository prior to this text.